# Does LINQ know how to join strings?

Tags: c#, string, linq

I want to search in full name string, that consists of first and last name. I get results only for first string (first name) and the second one (last name) is ignored. Is this functionality even supported? Thanks.

Names are stored in PostgreSQL DB. One table separated columns.

```
  public IQueryable<Domain.Domains.User.FrontendUser> Search(string searchedString)
  {
     var compareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
     const CompareOptions compareOptions = CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace;

     return GetAllNotDeleted()
         .Where(a => compareInfo.IndexOf($"{a.FirstName} {a.LastName}", searchedString, compareOptions) > 1)
         .Select(x => _frontendUserMapper.ToDomain(x));
    }
```

Comment: little bit confused... is this check first and last names which matched?

Comment: I very much doubt that EF will handle this conversion. Is it absolutely necessary to use IQueryable?

Comment: Example: Let's say I have Napoleon Bonaparte (first name, last name) in my records. When I type in my search Napoleon B then I want to find this record.

Comment: what is the generated sql? can you give concrete examples that arent working? why are you using 1 as threshold instead of -1? IndexOf will return a 0-based index in case of match, so both 0 and 1 are values that represent a match.

Comment: You are right. Lost minus symbol during copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Bad conditions. I checked for value of 1 insted of -1. Thank you Jota.Toledo.

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works fine. the problem is that `IndexOf` results in -1 if no match is found and if match is found it returns the index of the first match which could be 0. So you should not check if `IndexOf() > 1` because this will only result in true if you match something at index 2 or later. you should do `IndexOf() >= 0` or `IndexOf() != -1`